# statement and condition if logic for removing chat

Tags: php, mysql

I have project that use chat application. I have already read the answer here about how to delete message from a user but it will not be deleted from another user. Still, I am stuck of doing it. I can delete it by not using delete the row but update idSender(idPengirim) field only. idReceiver(idPenerima) field still remains. In addition, it is always removed from both of users. Here it is method:

```
public function deleteChat($pengirim,$penerima,$idChat){

    $query = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mess WHERE idChat=:idchat");
    $query->execute(array(":idchat" => $idChat));

    while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $row['idPengirim'] = $pengirim;
        $row['idPenerima'] = $penerima;
        if($pengirim == -1 && $penerima == -1){
            $query = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM mess WHERE idChat = :idchat");
            $query->execute(array(":idchat"=>$idChat));


        }
        if ($pengirim!=-1){
            $query = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE mess SET idPengirim = -1");
            $query->bindParam(":idchat",$idChat);
            $query->execute();

            return $query;
        }

        if ($penerima!=-1){
            $query = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE mess SET idPenerima = -1");
            $query->bindParam(":idchat", $idChat);
            $query->execute();

            return $query;
        }

    }
}
```

I have no idea what should I do. I hope I will find guides here, Thank you. Sorry for my broken English.

Comment: Why are you setting `$row['idPengirim'] = $pengirim;`? You are not doing anything with that. Actually you don't read from the `$row` array at all, so why do you have a `SELECT` statement? And in your `UPDATE` statements you are binding the `:idchat` variable, but you don't use it in your queries.

Comment: I see, I forget to delete the part of binding :idchat. And for $row['idPengirim'] = $pengirim; I set it for using it in another page, it is same with another parameters ($penerima,$idChat).

Comment: Keep in mind that `UPDATE mess SET idPengirim = -1` will set the value for all rows in the `mess` table. Setting `$row['idPengirim'] = $pengirim;` still doesn't make sense because there is no "another page" inside the function you posted. And what is the actual question you are asking?

Comment: Oh my bad, I forget to add WHERE in UPDATE mess SET idPengirim = -1. That query should be UPDATE mess SET idPengirim = -1 WHERE idChat = :idchat and keep binding the 'idchat'. I mean 'another page' is page that I would use my method on it. I'm sorry if my question don't make it clear. I am still a beginner.  My question is I want to delete message only from one user, not both of them. The deletion has worked, but at both of users, not one of them. Could you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

i think the right way to build a chat application is build a table spacified for `chats` and contain a `userFromId` and `userToId`. when you get a chat you send a request `get * from chat where userFromId=.. and userToId =.....` and when you delete a chat you do the same: `delete * from chat where..` i dont know how do you build it but in this way you not have a problems with "chat deleted from one user and not deleted from another"..

Comment: I have tables consist of id, idReceiver, idSender, and idChat. The problem is when I click delete button, idSender will change as -1. It was always like that, idReceiver didn't change at all and of course the deletion works, but it worked for both of users, not one of the users (Sender and Receiver). I just confused about it, maybe the statement above didn't match yet? Have an idea?

Comment: why set the userId as -1 and not delete this row from the table?

Comment: Because I should keep the data if another user doesn't delete the message from history message.